# Object keep replacing the current object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

My goal is to add new object in `days` array but it keeps replacing the existing object in the array. I couldn't figure out the problem.

Current result :

```
[{"name":"Tuesday","value":"Tues"},{"name":"Tuesday","value":"Tues"},{"name":"Tuesday","value":"Tues"}]
```

Here is the code:

```
var query = "Sunday,Monday,Tuesday";
var day = {day: "", value: ""}
var days = [];

query.split(",").map(p => {

 switch (p) {
      case "Sunday":
        day ["day "] = "Sunday";
        day ["value"] = "Sun";
        break;
      case "Monday":
        day ["day "] = "Monday";
        day ["value"] = "Mon";
        break;
      case "Tuesday":
         day ["day "] = "Tuesday";
         day ["value"] = "Tues";
        break;
    }

    days.push(day);
});

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(days);
```

Comment: You need to make a new `day` object on each iteration of the loop. Basically just move the `var day` declaration to inside the `.map()` callback.

Comment: yep. silly me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object as return value in the `switch` statement. If no string is found, return an object with empty strings.

This approach uses the returned array from [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var query = "Sunday,Monday,Tuesday",
    days = query.split(",").map(p => {
        var day = { day: "", value: "" };
        switch (p) {
            case "Sunday": return { day: "Sunday", value: "Sun" };
            case "Monday": return { day: "Monday", value: "Mon" };
            case "Tuesday": return { day: "Tuesday", value: "Tues" };
        }
        return { day: "", value: "" };
    });

console.log(days);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The current code keeps pushing one object reference on to the result array; defining `day` inside the `map` callback would fix the problem, but causing [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) isn't the intent of `map`.

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) accepts a callback parameter which should return the transformed value for each element. The return of `map` itself is the new mutated result array. The callback should not push onto an external array.

Using a `switch` statement is verbose and difficult to maintain, resulting in a lot of repeated code.

```js
const query = "Sunday,Monday,Tuesday";
const days = query.split(",").map(e => {
  return {day: e, value: e.substr(0, 3)};
});

console.log(days);
```

I noticed you wanted `"Tues"` to be a 4-character abbreviation while `"Sun"` and `"Mon"` are three. I'd recommend a separate object to store these transformations if this is indeed the desired result:

```js
const query = "Sunday,Monday,Tuesday";
const abbreviations = {Tuesday: "Tues"};
const days = query.split(",").map(e => {
  return {day: e, value: abbreviations[e] || e.substring(0, 3)};
});

console.log(days);
```

Essentially, this checks if we have a special abbreviation specified, else just fall back on the first three characters.